# Fields For Not Working for Has Many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for

I'm currently building a form for a model and am having trouble developing the associated model forms for the form.

The error I'm receiving:

```
undefined method `tradie_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_TradieCategory:0xd0f9d78>
```

The form code looks like:

```
= form_for @data[:tradie], url: { action: "update_tradie" } do |tradie|

  # This doesn't work
  = tradie.fields_for :tradie_categories, @data[:tradie].tradie_categories do |category|
    = category.text_field :tradie_id

  # However this fields_for does
  = tradie.fields_for :tradie_locations, @data[:tradie].tradie_locations do |location|
    = location.text_field :address
```

The `Tradie` model has a `has_many` relationship with the `TradieCategory` model and the `TradieCategory` model has a `belongs_to` relationship with `Tradie`. I also verified that `TradieCategory` has a field `tradie_id`.

In the form above, `@data[:tradie]` equals the instance of the `Tradie` model. Whenever I call `tradie_categories` or `tradie_locations` they are calling the associated model data of `TradieCategory` and `TradieLocation`.

Finally, in my view code, if I run `= @data[:tradie].tradie_categories.to_a`, I'm returned on my html page

```
[#<TradieCategory id: 2, tradie_id: 2, category_id: 1, created_at: "2013-09-08 19:50:10", updated_at: "2013-09-08 19:50:10">]
```

I have no idea what could be wrong with this. What's the problem and how could I fix this?

Comment: I think if you used parentheses you'd understand what's going on in here `- tradie.fields_for(:tradie_categories, @data[:tradie].tradie_categories) do |category|`

Comment: I understand what's going on with the parameters. For a reason I don't know it's not working. In that same form I have another `fields_for` and that works fine.

Comment: Oh come on. You got error that a method (which is supposed to be AR method) got called on collection. Can you show the other form?

Comment: Updated the code in the question.

Comment: And what's the definition for `.tradie_categories` and `.tradie_locations`? Code please!

Comment: What do you mean definition?

Comment: Can you add a debugger right above `= category.text_field :tradie_id` and show what it says when you attempt to do `category.object.tradie_id`? You may find that `category.object` isn't what you thought it was or something like that. I'm also wondering if perhaps there is a missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tradie_categories` in the `Tradie` model.

Comment: That was it. The `accepts_nested_attributes_for` was missing. I thought I placed it in there. Post your comment as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tradie_categories` in the `Tradie` model?

Comment: I did but the answerer hasn't given credit. I'll give you the bounty if the person doesn't respond.

Comment: cool.  give them credit if they put an answer, otherwise i'll happily take the bounty!

Comment: Ugh sorry man. I just remembered about it and the bounty expired. Sorry. :(